# Pagination Operator for querying in Azure CosmosDB Collection

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any MySQL's OFFSET like identifier available for querying Azure CosmosDB which can help in Pagination, though it has **TOP** which is LIMIT equivalent but without **OFFSET** equivalent, pagination would be tough to do.

In SDK, there is a support to use continuation token for the subsequent call but in plain SQL form, if there is any operator, it would be good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour as you describe it doesn't exist in CosmosDB yet.

It is the most [requested feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take) and it is masked as `Planned` so it will happen but CosmosDB wasn't built with this feature.

You can work around it with Continuation tokens and the `TOP` keyword which is the `.Take()` in LINQ, but fast and cost efficient skip and take isn't there yet.

Update

If you are using the C# you can use [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) which has support for skip and take pagination. More info on it can be found [here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#pagination).

*Disclaimer, I'm the creator of Cosmonaut*

Comment: Thanks Nick for providing answer!

Answer (score 1):

SKIP AND TAKE is now available in Cosmos DB via a new **`OFFSET LIMIT`** clause:

```
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c._ts OFFSET 3 LIMIT 20
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit